# How to update Zlib library on Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, zlib, libz

I am trying to update Zlib on Xcode 7.1

According to zlib.h on /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/include, My Zlib version is 1.2.5.

I am trying to update it to 1.2.8

Is there a way to update xcode lib ?

I try to add libz.1.2.8.dylib to Link Binary With Libraries however my app still using zlib 1.2.5

Thanks in advance

Comment: Compile it yourself.  See [this](https://gist.github.com/dulaccc/75f1f49f53e544cef549) github repo,

Comment: I compiled it already using that link and I add dylib to Link Binary With Libraries, but my app still using 1.2.5

Comment: OK, well if you are trying to use it via `.dylib`, you are aware that it will have to be bundled with the `.app` and only iOS 8+ supports this?  There may be complications for other `.dylib` files that want to use zlib as well.  Things might get messy...

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this by:

1. Rename libz.1.2.8.dylib to libz.dylib and add it to Link Binary With Libraries
2. Add zlib.h using module.modulemap. Example

   `module zlib [system] {
       header "zlib/zlib.h"
       export *
   }`
3. Select the target -> *Build Settings* -> *Swift Compiler Search Path* -> Add folder where you store module map on **Search Path**
4. use `import zlib` to use zlib

Referenced from https://github.com/1024jp/NSData-GZIP